# Как ввести данные stdin при выполнении node exec?

Tags: node.js

После выполнения команды, далее выводится требование ввести пароль. А как ответить на это требование?

```
exec('pg_dumpall > all.sql', {
    cwd: 'C:/'
}, function(err, output) {
});
```

Comment: Может сразу подставить пароль в аргументы запускаемой команды?

Comment: Он его запрашивает трижды. Поэтому не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задача интересная. Мне кажется, что решить можно как-то так:

```
const execa = require('execa')
const { PassThrough } = require('stream')

const input = new PassThrough()
const command = 'pg_dumpall > all.sql'

execa.shell(command, {input}).then(() => console.log('success'))

input.write(process.env.PWD)
input.write(process.env.PWD)
input.write(process.env.PWD)
```

Думаю, что за счёт того, что мы записали пароль тремя разными частями, он и прочитается 3 раза. Я использую тут модуль [`execa`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/execa), т.к. он более удобен, чем стандартный exec.

Comment: Спасибо. А как то более надежно есть варианты, чтобы возникало событие запроса ввода?

Comment: @manking Нет такого понятия как "событие ввода". stdin - это обычный nodejs поток, также как и stdout.

Comment: Но у меня же появляется текст с просьбой ввести пароль. Значит это событие. И у меня не работает этот код, всё равно висит требование ввода пароля.

Comment: @manking Этот текст появляется потому, что вы в stdout пишете, что хотите прочитать данные, а программа в это время молча ждёт данных из потока ввода.

Comment: Так как изменить ваш ответ, чтобы он передавал данные в поток stdin?

Comment: @manking Он уже пишет данные в stdin `input.write`.

Comment: Получается невозможно решить ту задачу которую я описал? Передавать данные в поток stdin, тогда когда это требуется (когда он ждёт ввода пароля)?

Comment: Вообще когда копирую ваш код, то получаю ошибку 

_stream_writable.js:346
  var len = state.objectMode ? 1 : chunk.length;
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:346:41)
    at PassThrough.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:288:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\inetpub\bb\server\projects\poseidon\poseidon_backup_sql.js:83:7)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)

Comment: @manking Я не тестировал код, возможно да, не работает как надо Идея в том, чтобы записать пароль в stdin, , а дочерний процесс сам разберётся и прочитает. Почитайте как работает stream, child_process и  потоки ввода / вывода в линуксах.

Comment: У меня windows 7, Ищу универсальный подход или хотя бы под винду. Не возможно, а точно не работает. В коде ошибки.